# VSCode powershell function signature intellisense suggestions

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want VSCode to show powershell function signatures within the open parentheses.

For example, if I create a file `file.ps1`, enable the Powershell extension, and then type into the editor

```
"my string".Replace(
```

when the cursor is after the `(` I want a popover dialog to show the possible function signature parameters.

I know the [`System.String.Replace` has multiple function parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0). I would like intellisense to display a popover like:

```
Replace(Char, Char)
Replace(String, String)
Replace(String, String, StringComparison)
Replace(String, String, Boolean, CultureInfo)
```

How do I enable VSCode intellisense to show powershell function signature popovers?

Comment: When I type "my string". the intelligence kicks in and it does tell me what functions are available and their parameters.  Kind of annoying compared to VS Studio, but it does work.  Is you VSCode failing to do this?  There may be setting that changes that if it isn't.

Comment: "_it does tell me what functions are available and their parameters._" @Darin I am able to see possible functions when the cursor is next to the `.` in `"mystring".`. However, when I choose a function, like `Replace`, then intellisense goes away. I wanted a better display of function signatures when the cursor is _within_ the parentheses, i.e. when the cursor as after the `(` in `"my string".Replace(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I delete the ending "e" in "Remove", and retype the "e", this drop down appears.  Likewise, if in the middle of typing "Replace", I press **Ctrl+Space**, as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense), the dropdown box appears.  At far right of this box is a little arrow that when you move your mouse over will pop up another smaller white box saying "Read More".
[image]

When I click the arrow, or pressing **Ctrl+Space** again, it will expand another box to the right. If I move my mouse over that text and wait a second, a smaller white box appears that is a little easer to read.
[image]

Afaik, this is mostly what VSCode has to offer for intellisense.  If this isn't working for you, then let us know and hopefully someone can figure out why.

Comment: It appears that's it, I hadn't noticed the little `>`. I'm disappointed in this design choice by the VSCode team. For functions with several parameters, as I fill-in the parameters I often forget some, so I have to then try to bring up the intellisense again by moving the cursor around, and possibly deleting characters. Very tedious.
Thanks @Darin .

Comment: James, I absolutely agree that it is bad design choice!  I only discovered the little arrow in that box within the last month or two, but I started PowerShell programming, and using VSCode, around January of last year.  That is long time to miss such a fundamental feature.  The arrow doesn't show unless you move your mouse over that line!  Why?  That alone is just wrong.  But you would think they could have built it to work like VS Studio.  Anyways, I hope you have a lot of success with PowerShell, and have a good day!